# pass javascript model to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I can't figure out what I am missing here. I have a javascript model that I'm building here is a dumbed down version of it. Does anyone see why my model isn't being passed to my Controller with data?

Javascript model that is getting built: (This does populate correctly)

```
var myModel = {
    ThresholdDetailId: thresholdDetailID,
    ThresholdId: thresholdId,
    OwnerName: ownerName,
    SelectedNodeType: selectedNodeType,
    GroupID: groupId
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax(
{
    context: this,
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Threshold/EditThreshold/',
    data: { model: myModel },
    success: function (result) {
        //do stuff
    },
    error: function () {
        error();
    }
});
```

Whenever the Action gets hit on the controller the model is empty.

Here is the signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EditThreshold(ThresholdDetail model)
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!!, So close but so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap `myModel` in an outer object with a `model` property (unless the viewmodel you're ultimately binding to is set up the same way, which seems unlikely):

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Threshold/EditThreshold/',
    data: myModel, // <-------
    success: function (result) {
        //do stuff
    },
    error: function () {
        error();
    }
});
```